# Full Calendar view in HTML Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show a full calendar in my HTML page, I need it so the user can add their timetables, appointments etc

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/appointments.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

and my javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  })
})
```

This code shows the following on my web page - this is pure text that does nothing, not sure if there is a problem with css or what

> February 2015
>   today
>
> Sun   Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
>
> 1234567
>
> 891011121314

Comment: Are you sure all of the script and CSS files are loading? What errors do you see in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: Hello! Yes they are all loading, that is the first thing that I checked, the problem is there is no error is the console, which is one of the reasons why I can't seem to understand where I am going wrong here

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, in your Javascript you have fullCalendar, in your script and link tags you have fullcalendar, are you sure function is called `fullCalendar`?

Comment: Any particular reason you're loading both the minified and full versions of fullcalendar? That can't be *helping*.

Comment: @cli `fullCalendar()` is the correct spelling of the method: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/

Comment: Yeah, the function is called fullCalendar() - @cli

Comment: @PaulRoub - which one should I go for then minified or full version?

Comment: They're functionally identical. The minified version is smaller, and better for production use. The un-minified version is human-readable and debuggable. Same goes for the duplicate `fullcalendar.css` / `fullcalendar.min.css`

Comment: I removed the minified version and it didnt help

Comment: There's a definitely a CSS issue - it's not loading, or there are conflicts with other classes in your own CSS, etc. Hard to tell without seeing a (non-)working example.